# Symfony2 Form entity

Tags: symfony

I have a problem, I want to create a simple search form with a filter assembly. These filters are attributes that belong to attribute groups.

```
group 1

[] Attribute 1

[] Attribute 2

[] Attribute 3


group 2

[] Attribute 1

[] Attribute 2

[] Attribute 3
```

But the problem is that I can not do (graphic aspect)

```
$builder->add('attribut', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'RestoFrontBundle:Attribut',
                'group_by' => 'groupeAttribut.id',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(AttributRepository $er) {
                                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                                                ->join("a.groupeAttribut", 'g')
                                                ->where("a.statut = 1");
                                    }
                ))
             ->getForm();
```

Also I can not manage the game if the checkbox has been checked.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to the "Click to add features" mutliple select from http://stayattache.com

Comment: Yes but with checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You note that the graphic aspect is the hard part. That is due to the way checkboxes are used in HTML. Unlike select inputs there is no notion of an optgroup. The closest analog for checkboxes would be a `fieldset` with a `legend`.

You may want explore using a [Choice Field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) rather than an entity type. Provide your choices via some provider function within which you format the options array(s) whether or not you retrieved them from a database. ( For the record, that's exactly how I populate the select at http://stayattache.com which has multiple places to retrieve options from. ) You may even want to explore creating your own form field type and template to format the output. Checkout the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) on creating your own field type.

I hope that helps a bit. There are probably plenty of other ways to approach this as well.